# How to get the Transform panel to show up again in Video Sequencer?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, panel

You know anytime you Move, Rotate or Scale something in the 3D Viewport, a box pops up in the lower-left corner that shows how much and by what axis you did the transformation? This is super handy because it lets us precisely overwrite our transformations on objects. This used to pop up in the video sequencer also, but I started a new project using the Video Editor loadout and when I transform something, it doesn't pop up. Hitting "T" doesn't make it show up either. Where did it go? How can I get it back? I need it. This is Blender 2.80 on Windows 10, btw

Answer (score 1):

Press F9 to adjust last operation.

It was never implemented in the VSE to pop up automatically like in the 3D View, but it'll soon be: https://developer.blender.org/D6210